# Const member function and typedef, C++

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, typedef, member-functions

Suppose we want to declare const member function via `typedef`:

```
typedef int FC() const;
typedef int F();

struct A
{
   FC fc;         // fine, we have 'int fc() const'
   const F f;    // not fine, 'const' is ignored, so we have 'int f()'
};
```

Since `const` is ignored the program compiles fine. Why `const` is ignored for function? Since we can form const pointer in this way the only thing I can think of is 'C heritage'. Does standard say anything about it?

Comment: `int () const` is mostly a half type, as it may apply only to class to have member functions.

Comment: It cannot be "C heritage" as C doesn't have member functions.

Comment: Yes, but in C we still can have:

typedef int F();
const F f;

even though 'int f() const' may be syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Interesting question. Why is it downvoted? It seems that the `const` before `F` is completely ignored. I checked by printing its type and was expecting that it might be `const int (A::*)()` at least. But No, it's simply `int (A::*)()` only.

Comment: The only explanation is that const applied to function in C++ is not 'full-right' type.

Comment: And `const` is ignored not only before `F`, but also after, in a declaration like `F const fc`

Comment: Yes, since order of 'const' and 'F' is not essential.

Comment: This is a "why is the language the way it is?" question, which we generally cannot answer; only the people actively involved in designing the language can answer, and they might not remember (since this has been this way for a very long time).  The committee publishes a "Rationale" document that explains _some_ of the more confusing design decisions, but I suspect it doesn't cover this one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C++ 14 standard, **[dcl.fct]** pt. 7:

> The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top
>   of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [ Note: a function type that has a
>   cv-qualifier-seq is not a cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types. — end note ]

Example:

```
typedef void F();

struct S {
    const F f; // OK: equivalent to: void f();
};
```

So, this is a correct behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This change is made by [CWG 295](http://wg21.link/CWG295), essentially to ease generic programming. Consider:

```
template<class F>
void meow(const F& f) { f(); }
void purr();

meow(purr);
```

Ignoring the extra `const` allows this to work.